# Help understanding a proof (Linear Transformation)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

> On a V vectorial space
>
> we have that
>
> $T(x+y) = Tx - Ty$
>
> $T(\alpha x) = \alpha Tx$ , for $\alpha \geq 0$
>
> Prove that T is linear.

I tried some stuff by myself and then I found an answer online, but I can't completely understand it.

It goes like this:

> Suppose $\alpha < 0 $. We have $T[(\alpha-\alpha)x]= T(0x)=0Tx=0$

That part I get.

But then it goes,

> so that $0=T( \alpha x- \alpha x) = T( \alpha x) + T(- \alpha x) = T(\alpha x) - \alpha T(  x) $
>
> Thus, $T(\alpha x)= \alpha Tx$ if $\alpha < 0 $

The part I don't quite get is, how you get this equality:

> $T( \alpha x- \alpha x) = T( \alpha x) + T(- \alpha x)  $

Comment: I believe that equality should only hold when $T(x+y) = Tx + Ty$, which is not the case in your problem. Probably the answer you found online did have this assumption

Answer (score 1):

For any vector $v$, let $u=\frac v2$.  Then $$Tv=T(u+u)=Tu-Tu=0$$  by the first property.
Therefore, $T$ must be the zero mapping, which is trivially linear.

Answer (score 1):

If both conditions works for any vectors $x,y$ then $T(x)=0$ for all $x$.

First of all take $\alpha=0$ in the second condition, then $T(0)=0$.

Now take $x=0$ in the first condition. It give us $T(y)=-T(y)\to T(y)=0$, for all $y$.

By the way, your doubt is pertinent. The online solution is wrong. The correct expression should be, $0=T(\alpha x+(-\alpha x))=T(\alpha x)-T(-\alpha x)$.

Comment: Oh I get it.Yeah I did a similar thing by myself concluding that it was in fact the zero mapping, but the answer I found on the book threw me off.